# How capture a window with correct dimensions?

Tags: delphi, graphics, screen-capture, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm testing for [this code](https://delphidabbler.github.io/delphi-tips/tips/186.html) example (that use [`PrintWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-printwindow) api) to capture a specific window by handle, and saw that window captured is greater than original (when captured with full desktop). There's a possibility to capture the window with same dimensions equals to original?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edition:**

For example suposse that i want capture the body of a site on Internet Explorer:

```
var
  Title: array [0 .. 255] of Char;
begin
  GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow, Title, 255);
  if Title <> '' then
  begin
    if ContainsStr(string(Title), '- Internet Explorer') then
    begin
      WindowHandle := FindWindow(nil, PChar(string(Title)));
      WindowHandle := FindWindowEx(WindowHandle, 0, 'Frame Tab', nil);
      WindowHandle := FindWindowEx(WindowHandle, 0, 'TabWindowClass', nil);
      WindowHandle := FindWindowEx(WindowHandle, 0, 'Shell DocObject View',
      nil);
      WindowHandle := FindWindowEx(WindowHandle, 0, 'Internet Explorer_Server', nil); 
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Then using the code of linked answer, the 1st handle of IE will be with right size on screenshot, already the last (*Internet Explorer_Server*) will be captured big. I'm searching by a way to offset the size of screenshot to not stretch.

[image]

---

**Edition 2:**

My goal is [align remote mouse clicks on handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67371813/how-align-mouse-clicks-x-y-with-a-specific-window-handle). Is true that i already have a solution like you can see in my [last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67371813/how-align-mouse-clicks-x-y-with-a-specific-window-handle/67371952#comment119089334_67371952), but this solution not is working if i'm seeing screenshot only of website body like showed on gif and said above. Then i'm asking about **size of screenshot** because i think that probaly is it the problem.

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need `FindWindow()`, as you already have the `HWND` from `GetForegroundWindow()`. If there are multiple IE windows open to the same site, your `FindWindow()` is not guaranteed to find the correct window.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, i know. But on IE, if you want perform mouse clicks by handle on website body, is possible only on handle where classname is *Internet Explorer_Server*.

Comment: I know that. I was referring only to your `FindWindow(nil, PChar(string(Title)))` call, not the `FindWindowEx()` calls.  You can get rid of that `FindWindow()` call, just save the `HWND` from `GetForegroundWindow()` to your `WindowHandle` variable, eg: `WindowHandle := GetForegroundWindow(); GetWindowText(WindowHandle, Title, 255); ... WindowHandle := FindWindowEx(WindowHandle, ...);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, see my **Edition 2**.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the issue is that the screenshot stretches when in F11 mode, correct? I tried to reproduce this ([my code](https://pastebin.com/kLPTkjBS)), I get a bigger screenshot when IE is in F11 mode but the bmp is not stretched.

Comment: @whosrdaddy, then, i not understand why seems that i see stretched, filling all space of "viewer", as full desktop. See gif above more carefully. I think that right is screenshot of handle *`Internet Explorer_Server`* with same dimensions, like showed when taked a capture of full desktop. **"`So if I understand you correctly, the issue is that the screenshot stretches when in F11 mode, correct?`"** - And no, i'm not in F11 mode

Comment: so the gif shows the difference between handle of Explorer_Server and main window, I understand now, If I test this my BMP does not stretch. Can you edit your question and provide a complete example that exhibits this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem!. Happens that in a screen resolution of **1366x768**, the screenshot on handle *Internet Explorer_Server* will be **1366x650**, therefore now i must adapt mouse clicks based in this resolution and not on original resolution of screen (1366x768) like done before (linked question).

Server:

```
X := Round((X * {ResolutionX}1366) / Image1.Width);
Y := Round((Y * {ResolutionY}650) / Image1.Height);
```

---

Client:

```
PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(X, Y));
PostMessage(WindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(X, Y));
```

Comment: The difference looks to be the task bar size. The task bar can be moved to the sides of the screen, set to auto-hide or resized. To test make the taskbar large and on the left.